# Return a sequence with dynamic type in scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, return-type

I'm trying to define a function, which should return a range from `1` to `n` of type `T`. Here, `T` is given as user-input and an `implicit def` method is available to convert `int` to `T`. I.e., what I would like to have, but doesn't work, is:

```
def createSeq[T](n: Int): Seq[T] = 
  1 to n map _.asInstanceOf[T]
```

For example, I can call `createSeq[Int](3)`, which works like a charm. However, when I call `createSeq[String](3)`, it still returns `Vector(1,2,3)`, which contains integers and not strings.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve makes little sense if you specify `T` as is. Please explain what you expect your code to return with the following call:

`case object SpaceStation`
`createSeq[SpaceStation](42)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's define `createSeq`, asking for an implicit conversion `Int => T` from `Int` to `T`, as:

```scala
def createSeq[T](n: Int)(implicit toT: Int => T): Seq[T] =
  1.to(n).map(toT)
```

Then you can do:

```scala
scala> createSeq[Int](3)
res: Seq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Let's add an implicit conversion `Int => String`:

```scala
implicit def toStr(n: Int): String = n.toString
```

Then you can do:

```scala
scala> createSeq[String](3)
res: Seq[String] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Note: this last `Vector(1, 2, 3)` is of type `Seq[String]`, it is actually `Vector("1", "2", "3")` but `"` are omitted.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I need.